Can av_freep() be replaced directly with the following implementation?
After reviewing the implementation of av_freep(void* arg) in the FFmpeg documentation, I have some questions. Specifically, can its code be simplified to the following form?
FFmpeg Implementation:
void av_freep(void* arg)
{
    void* val;

    memcpy(&val, arg, sizeof(val));
    memcpy(arg, &(void*){ NULL }, sizeof(val));
    av_free(val);
}



my version:
void av_freep(void* arg)
{
    free(*arg);
    *arg = NULL;
}


Are you sure your replacement for av_free is valid?

After reading the source code, I refined the part I understood. I think if I simply release the memory and set the pointer to null, I can write it like this, but I don't understand what the disadvantages are and what the advantages of the source code are. So I would like to ask you for advice.
